# Find the value of $b(100)-b(97)-b(96)$ if $b(0)=1$ with given conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

> If for any series $b(n)=2b(n-1)$ when $b(n)$ is odd number and $b(n)=b(n-1)$ if $b(n)$ is even number. then
>
> Find the value of $b(100)-b(97)-b(96)$ if $b(0)=1$

Our Approach:

I could not Analyse the result coming from the equations

$b(100)$=$b(99)$=$2b(98)$=$2b(97)$=$4b(96)$

$b(96)$=$b(95)$=$2b(94)$=$2b(93)$=$4b(92)$=$16b(88)$=$64b(84)$=$256b(80)$=
$1024b(76)
$
$b(97)$=$2b(96)$=$2b(95)$=$4b(94)$=$4b(93)$  etc

Similarly,

$b(96)$=$4b(92)$

$b((92)$=$4b(88)$

$b(88)$=$4b(84)$

$b(84)$=$4b(80)$

How to analyse this Answer better?

Comment: Do you mean "when $n$ is an odd/even number", gving $$b(n) = 2^{\lceil n/2\rceil}$$? If you mean "when $b(n-1)$ is an odd/even number" you get $b(n)=2$ for every $n\ge 1$. And if you really mean what you write, there is no possible value for $b(1)$ that meets your specification.

Comment: @Henning Makholm I have reproduced  you what exactly is stated in the problem.Yes it can different interpretations.probably we have to assume in finding the solution because the only other thing have is that Ans is $2^$48

Comment: x @justin: What is reproduced here makes no sense. In the case $n=1$ it works out to "$b(1)=2$ if $b(1)$ is odd, and $b(1)=1$ if $b(1)$ is even", which is absurd.

Comment: But if we do change the specification to ".. when $n$ is odd/even ..", then $b(n)=2^{\lceil n/2\rceil}$ does give us $$ b(100)-b(97) - b(96) = 2^{50}-2^{49}-2^{48} = (4-2-1)2^{48} = 2^{48} $$